# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP-Pavilion G6 Issues

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, hp-pavilion

I've recently bought a HP Pavilion G6 preloaded with Windows 8. I don't like Windows 8 so I want to install Ubuntu. I am new to Linux and have been looking though the Ask Ubuntu and have noticed that there are a lot of issues with new HP machines.

I've followed all the install instructions and can boot from the DVD.

I installed Ubuntu but its almost as if the information is not translating onto my hard drive. When I reload Windows 8 I can see that a new partition has been created but I am unable to boot to Ubuntu.

I've done this a good few times but I have had no success.

I have been into my BIOS and have turned off Secure Boot which I have noticed has been an issue with others but I have still had no luck.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Pavilion G6 on which I am successfully stably running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for over 18 months.  Before that I was not able to upgrade because the wireless "card" was not supported.  Audio was late in coming, as well; but once they were supported, I moved Windows over and installed 12.04 successfully.  I recently researched upgrading to 12.10 and decided against it due to the same factors--reports of a lack of drivers for the G6.  I would suggest you consider 12.04 if you are really interested in getting a stable installation.